# Is there any restriction between Apache and PHP version

Tags: php, apache2

Is there any restriction between apache and php version? Suppose I am running Apache version 2.2. Am I restricted to certain PHP version (5.3?) such that beyond that version (5.4 or 5.5), PHP can't be run as an apache module?

To be more specific, is `mod_php` bound to certain PHP version?

Comment: mod_php isn't bound to a certain PHP version. It's an Apache module generated when PHP is compiled.http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php

Comment: So if i install php first and then apache2 it will not work corretly?

Comment: if you have a version of mod_php compiled for apache2.whatever then you just have to configure it in httpd.conf

Answer (score 4):

In general Apache doesn’t care what version of PHP you are using and PHP doesn’t really care what version of Apache you are using. I say “in general”, because there can be some extreme cases where you will most likely know you are getting into a mess before you even begin. But for common use, it’s not a worry.

For example, on my desktop I am using [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) running Apache version 2.2.25 and PHP 5.5.3. In fact I can toggle MAMP to use PHP 5.2.17 if need be. And in other setups you can have dozens of different PHP module versions you can select to load into Apache. Using Ubuntu 12.04 as an example you just have to edit this file:

```
/etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.load
```

And have it load whatever PHP module you wish to load:

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
```

The name `libphp5.so` has little to do with the contents. That is the name the file is given when compiled. For my own testing purposes when manually compiling I have renamed `libphp5.so` all of the following & it always worked fine:

```
LoadModule php5_module        /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp535.so
LoadModule php5_module        /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp533-gd.so
LoadModule php5_module        /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp530-gd.so
LoadModule php5_module        /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp529-gd.so
LoadModule php5_module        /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp525-gd.so
LoadModule php5_module        /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp516-gd.so
```

And I have even manually compiled PHP 5.1.6 —painful but doable & necessary for a project—on an Ubuntu 12.04 setup running Apache 2.2.25 without any issue. The biggest issue I ran into when compiling PHP 5.1.6 was simply ensuring I had the proper libraries loaded or installed on the system.  But that is a nightmare you don’t want to know about!

In general, an upgrade from PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.4 or 5.5 should be a relatively easy process. No worries.